# How to convert string to mysql datetime format?

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I am facing a difficulty in converting a string based datetime format to mysql date time format.

I tried the following

```
str latesttime =  "2\/11\/2015 8:04:06 PM";
string formatForMySql = Convert.ToDateTime(latestscreentime);
```

Not converted. also tried with parse 
And also

```
SimpleDateFormat from = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
SimpleDateFormat to = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = from.parse(latestscreentime);       // 01/02/2014
String mysqlString = to.format(date);
```

here error is

> 'SimpleDateFormat' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

But I download the `vjslib.dll` and add `using SimpleDateFormat;`

So could any one help me in solving this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change your string to DateTime

```
var latesttime = @"2/11/2015 8:04:06 PM";
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse(latesttime);
```

Now you can simply do,

```
var sqlDateFormat= dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little bit too late, but I want to point some other points also..

First of all, you *can't* have a `string` as;

```
string latesttime = "2\/11\/2015 8:04:06 PM";
```

because since it is a [regular string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx), you need to escape your `\` character since it is an [escape sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) character. You might wanna escape it as `"2\\/11\\/2015 8:04:06 PM"` or use *verbatim string literal* as `@"2\/11\/2015 8:04:06 PM"`

I don't think your `Convert.ToDateTime()` *ever* work with that string because none `CultureInfo` have `d\\/MM\\/yyyy h:mm:ss tt` format as a [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Instead of that, you can use custom date and time parsing with [`DateTime.TryParseExact` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) like;

```
string s = @"2\/11\/2015 8:04:06 PM";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, @"d\\/MM\\/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None,out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

Since `\` is an escape character in custom date and time parsing, you need to escape with double slash as `\\`.

There is no `SimpleDateFormat` class in .NET Framework. I think you are mixing it Java's [`SimpleDateFormat` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

In .NET Framework, *usually* [`DateTime.ToString` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.110).aspx) is used when you try to get string representation of your `DateTime`. After you parsing, you can do these;

```
dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// Result will be 02/11/2015 08:04:06 PM

dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
// Result will be 2015-11-02 20:04:06
```

I used `InvariantCulture` as an `IFormatProvider` in first example because [The `"/"` custom format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning as *replace me with current culture or supplied culture date separator*. That's why it might generate different results in different cultures.